# Key-listener that Runs Concurrently With a Terminal Timer using Threads

Tags: python, macos, terminal, concurrency, python-multithreading

I am trying to make a timer that runs concurrently with a key-listener. The key-listener should perform a function when it takes a key and stop the timer. Below is the code I wrote. Though when I run it, the timer runs infinitely but the the key-listener does not listen for keys thus not print what it's supposed to.

Nota bene I am just getting into threading so the whole code I have written may be logically wrong in the paradigm of threading.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import os
import keyboard

run_timer = True
keep_scanning = True

def startTimer(seconds):
    while run_timer:
        for i in range(1, seconds):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system("clear")
            
def scanForInput():
    while keep_scanning:
        print(keep_scanning)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
            keep_scanning = False
            run_timer = False
            return "HIT"
            
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    f1 = executor.submit(startTimer, 4)
    f2 = executor.submit(scanForInput)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was hard to debug.  Your `scanForInput` func terminating because `keyboard` library `raise` `ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')` error when you have no root privileges, this is specified in the [doc](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/tree/8ea01e14fc823bae0720b9989afed3f6b966c697#known-limitations). The bad thing is `ThreadPoolExecutor` thread not log this error to stdout or stderr directly if we don't catch this error. I did some debug that this function is really working, and I have see that this function terminating after the `print(keep_scanning)` command, because i had no root privileges. So, to be able to use `keyboard` library in Linux,  we need to have `sudo(root)` privileges.

And second thing, you need to use `global` keyword to be able to update the `keep_scanning` and `run_timer` variables in the `scanForInput` function, but using `global` keyword is not good practice.

you can update your code like this :

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import os,threading
import keyboard

run_timer = True
keep_scanning = True

def startTimer(seconds):
    while run_timer:
        for i in range(1, seconds):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system("clear")
            
def scanForInput():
    global keep_scanning,run_timer
    try:
        while keep_scanning:
            print(keep_scanning)
            if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
                keep_scanning = False
                run_timer = False
                return "HIT"
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    f1 = executor.submit(startTimer, 4)
    f2 = executor.submit(scanForInput)
```

and you need to run this command with [sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) privileges like `sudo python3 mycode.py`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know I have to  manually catch errors in threadpools in order to print it out. Yes your code worked and got the job done.

Have a good day :D

Comment: You're welcome. Yes you can catch errors in `ThreadPoolExecutor` thread, and you can do specific action according to exception type